# List arbitrary number of elements from a json field (postgres)

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a json field in postgres db that contains data like

```
[{
    "value": "+1 968 730 5680",
    "label": "mobile",
    "primary": true
},{
    "value": "+1 909 169 4444",
    "label": "mobile",
    "primary": false
}]
```

I want to query this field to produce

```
+1 968 730 5680; +1 909 169 4444
```

Given that the number of elemets can vary.

I had enough brains to get the first element with 
`json_field -> 0 ->> 'value'`
but am totally stuck at producing a string with all elements.
Please help.

**UPDATE**
Following advice below, I get an error with statement

```
select d ->> 'value' as val
from analyst.person
cross join jsonb_array_elements(phone) as x(d)

ERROR:  column "phone" does not exist
LINE 3: cross join jsonb_array_elements(phone) as x(d)
```

another variant I tried

```
select d ->> 'value' as val
from analyst.person as person
cross join jsonb_array_elements(person.phone) as x(d)
```

gives error

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "person"
LINE 3: cross join jsonb_array_elements(person.phone) as x(d)
                                        ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "person", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest your json array, extract the value and aggregate it back into a string:

```
select string_agg(val, '; ')
from (
  select d ->> 'value' as val
  from the_table
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(the_json_colum) as x(d)
) t
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/VFSRY99127

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to play the newbie, but the part
(updated the question)
gives me error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Vémundr: sorry, forgot the `lateral`